# Vue.js migration to 2.0: Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined. (found in root instance)

Tags: vue.js

// Edit: I think i have the problem solved. i needed the standalone build from vue...

i have migrated my vue.js 1.0 app to vue.js 2.0 (with migration helper). But this error shows me in the console `Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined. (found in root instance)`.

Here is my simplified main.js:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Router from 'vue-router';

import SiteHeader from './components/Header.vue';
import Content from './components/Content/Content.vue';
import SiteFooter from './components/Footer.vue';

Vue.use(Router);

const router = new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  root: '/',
  routes: [
    { path: '/', component: Content }
  ]
});

new Vue({
  router,

 components: {
    SiteHeader, SiteFooter
  }
}).$mount('body');
```

The `Content.vue` is an normal `vue` file with template and script (nothing special here).

My ´router-view` is defined in an laravel.blade file

```
 @if(Request::is('login'))
  <login></login>
 @else
  <site-header></site-header>
  <router-view></router-view>
  <site-footer></site-footer>
 @endif
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For starters, you are not allowed to mount to the body element in Vue 2.0.

Also, as the error message states, you have not provided a template or render function.

I assume (as you did not show) you have template markup directly in the HTML page.

This *can* work, but only with the "standalone" version of Vue. However, the default export of Vue's npm package is the "runtime build", which can't parse such templade code.

Further information here:

https://vuejs.org/guide/installation.html#Standalone-vs-Runtime-only-Build

Comment: I told him that he needs the standalone package, and the linked documentation for Vue.js, which explains how to do that. Does that not count? Do I actually have to spell it out? (serious question, not 100% familiar with SO rules / netiquette)

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood before. You are good here. Delete my previous comment.